# How I can find the list of Sybase Indexes for a given database?

Tags: indexing, isql

How I can find the list of Indexes for a given database in Sybase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Query against sysobjects and sysindexes:
SELECT o.name,
       i.name
  FROM sysobjects o
  JOIN sysindexes i
    ON (o.id = i.id)
```

Documentation on the interpretation of the sysobjects and sysindexes system tables is available on the Sybase web-site.

Load up stored procedure library from http://www.edbarlow.com/ and type in 
sp__helpindex

or use the Sybase-provided sp_helpindex which expects the table-name as a parameter.

Comment: sp_helpindex ... perfect!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Object_name(id)
FROM   sysindexes si
WHERE  indid > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a complete list of indexes in Sybase ASE we can use the following query -

**select 
  si.* 
from 
  sysobjects so, sysindexes si where so.id = si.id and si.indid > 0**

keepin in mind that a simple select between sysobjects system table and the sysindexes table will give table names along with index names if non-clustered indexes exists. Check the following link for more information -

[Sybase ASE - How to find index list in a sybase database](http://sybase-ase.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-find-index-list-in-sybase.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Sybase version SAP IQ/16, you can get list of indexes with following (table name my_table is case-sensitive):

```
select *
from sys.sysindexes
where tname = 'my_table';
```

You may check sybase version as follows:

```
select @@version
```