# How can find out if an index exists on a #table in Sysbase?

Tags: sql, indexing, sybase

I'm working in Sybase 15 SQL, in stored procedures.  I want to identify the indices on a temporary #table.  The usual techniques work on a permanent table but don't work on a temp table:

```
--look for an index on a temporary table

create table #T1( duff int)

create index idx99 on #T1(duff)

select * from sysindexes where name = 'idx99' --returns null rows !

--Look for an index on a permanent table

create table T1( duff int)

create index idx99 on T1(duff)

select * from sysindexes where name = 'idx99' --returns a row. OK for perm table.
```

Any ideas?

Bob

Comment: This may suit well here, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468183/how-i-can-find-the-list-of-sybase-indexes-for-a-given-database

Comment: @LWNirvana it's close.  The main difference is that temp tables keep their information in the temp database.

Comment: @user3041581 Hi, I noticed you haven't accepted my answer yet, and just wanted to follow up.

Answer (score 5):

For #tables, the query for finding the indexes is the same as a normal table, but it needs to be executed against the `tempdb` (or the temp database for your session if it's not default).

```
SELECT o.name, i.name
FROM tempdb..sysobjects o, tempdb..sysindexes i
WHERE o.id = i.id
AND o.name like "#T1%"
AND i.name like "idx99"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, if I correct a fault in the SQL: the fourth line should be   
    AND o.name like "#T1%"